# How to get Video.js load source from database instead of static files

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, video.js

I am trying to use Video Js project in my web page, so far all the examples I see requires use of static files hosted somewhere on a server, so if a user checks out the source code of the web page, they can easily download the video files. Instead of using video js like that, I would like to store video files in a database, I would like to stream them in the web page by making ajax calls. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You could save a reference to a video in a database, and then dynamically load that into a player. For example, you could have something like this returned from your server when you request a specific video:

```
GET /videos/1234.json

{
  "title": "some awesome video",
  "mime_type": "video/mp4"
  "source": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/your-bucket/video.mp4",
  "tags": ["awesome", "hooray", "video"]
}
```

So then when you request a video via AJAX, you could load it into your player like this:

```
someAjaxFunction(response) {
  videojs('your-player', {}, function() {
    var myPlayer = this;
    myPlayer.src({ type: response.mime_type, src: response.source });
  })
}
```

However, this doesn't really solve the problem of securing the content. Someone could still just grab the file from the final location, and there isn't a great answer for this right now with HTML5 video. The easiest thing to do would be to use something like [Cloud Front](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html), but that would only mean someone couldn't go back and download the video later without going through you.